# Delay when setting a annotation after tapping on map using skobbler sdk

Tags: android, skmaps

I'm using the skobbler sdk 2.2 and I want to show up a annotation after tapping the map. Unfortunately there is a significant delay between tapping and showing. It looks like the annotation shows up after a map refresh, but I couldn't find a public method responsible for that.
I've tried `mapView.invalidate()` and `mapView.updateAnnotaion(Annotation a)` but it doesn't seem to work this way.
Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: This is a known issue that will be fixed in the next SDK 2.3. As a workaround you can try: mapView.requestRender();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Skobbler's SDK 2.2 the solution is to add mapView.requestRender();

Comment: I added the new SDK 2.3 (replacing the .jar and .so file) but this issue still exists. Is there something to call instead now? mapView.requestRenderer() still helps

Comment: Thank Alx for your notice- we are checking it and we will let you know.